# If $A\oplus B\approx A$ then $B=0$?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Suppose $A,B$ abelian groups, such that $A\oplus B\approx A$, can I conclude that $B=0$?

If it's true, is there any hint how to prove it?

Comment: $\approx$ means isomorphic ?

Comment: You need more assumption than that, assuming $\oplus$ means direct sum.  It would hold for *finite* abelian groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No; consider $A=\Bbb{Z}^{\Bbb{N}}=\bigoplus_{n\in\Bbb{N}}\Bbb{Z}$.